# Saving turtle drawing in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I want to save a turtle drawing to and .eps file. Right now I use the function screen.getcanvas().postscript(file="test.eps")

The problem with that is it doesn't save the complete drawing. Before I draw, I don't know how big the drawing will be. When I drew, I have the biggest x and y value. The function like above just saves the drawing, what is on the canvas. If the drawing is really big, it is not completely on the canvas but I want to save the complete drawing. How do I do that?

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071633/turtle-module-saving-an-image

Comment: That doesn't save the complete drawing, only the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is to `setup()` the visible drawing, and  use `screensize()` to allocate the size of your image's total backing store.  And then use the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` arguments of the `postscript()` method to capture what you want.

The following will draw a visible circle and one too large to be seen in the window.  It will then dump the entire image with both circles:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 480)  # what's visible
screen.screensize(1200, 960)  # total backing store

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-100)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(100)  # visible

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-400)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(400)  # offscreen

canvas = screen.getcanvas()

canvas.postscript(file="test.eps", x=-600, y=-480, width=1200, height=960)

# wait for program to quit, then examine file 'test.eps'
```

Although you'll need to preallocate the large backing store (`screensize()`), you only need to dump as much of it as you want by keeping track of your user's actions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really struggeling. The screen.screensize() in the beginning is not even needed, it was the x and y as argument in postcript() that made the difference. You are a real life saver!